# How do I convert my fireplace switch into a thermostat switch?

Tags: thermostat, fireplace

I have a fireplace that's controlled by a regular on/off switch. How can I convert it into a thermostat switch so that the fireplace shuts off automatically whenever the room gets warm enough?

If it matters, I live in the US and it's a typical gas fireplace that I've seen in other condos.

Comment: Do you want anything fancy out of this thermostat, or do you just want it to sit there and control the setpoint all the time? Do you want your setting of the fireplace thermostat to have any impact on your condo's main HVAC system?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel all it has to do is turn off the fireplace when it gets warm enough. Bonus points if I can easily hook it up to Google Home or equivalent, so that I could run IFTTT with it

Comment: If you can use IoT, it's pretty simple; just get a thermometer/temp monitor that talks to your hub, and a regular-ass smart switch that the hub controls as needed.

Comment: Does your fireplace work with all the breakers for your condo turned off?

Comment: You might want to consider https://www.wifireremote.com/Home/Index

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel good question! Care to add an answer that explains what to do depending on whether or not it works?

Comment: @JonathanReez if your fireplace doesn't require the mains to be on to work (i.e. works in a power outage), then it uses what's called a *millivolt* control, which makes your question easier in some ways and harder in others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonathanReez if you find out that your fireplace is  millivolt controlled as @ThreePhaseEel says make sure that you purchase a thermostat rated for millivolt service. (it may make a difference).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to advice by @d.george, I bought [this thermostat](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00204WWGE) and it worked perfectly. I confirmed I needed a millivolt thermostat by turning off all electricity and making sure the fire place is still working.

[image]